# Android: Widget can only be used after reinstalling the application

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I am working on a project that will need to use a widget. The widget is able to be used normally except during the first installation of the application.

To be exact, if I delete the application and install it, the widget cannot be loaded and show "Problem loading widget" but if I reinstall it again without uninstalling it (using 'Run App' in android studio), the widget will become normal.

Just to mention, if I didn't change the code and press 'Run App', the widget will remain unusable. "Reinstall" the application somehow "solves" the bug.

It seems like the widget is not configured well for the first time, but I cannot figure out the real reason and get rid of that bug.

The large amount of setTextViewText() should not be the problem since the bug is still there even if I commented them out. If someone knows how to make that part into a loop, please tell me how to do so, I cannot figure out a way to do that in remoteView.

Maybe I should do something on onEnabled() like forcing the widget to have the same performance as reinstalling the application?

P.S. The CSV that need to be read should be created in the onCreate() of the mainActivity so it should have been created before the widget trying to read it?

```
class TimetableWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    var intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
    var remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.timetable_widget)
//    val timetable_data = initialize(context)
    val timetable_data = readCSV(context)

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_1_1, timetable_data[0])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_2_1, timetable_data[1])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_3_1, timetable_data[2])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_4_1, timetable_data[3])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_5_1, timetable_data[4])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_6_1, timetable_data[5])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_7_1, timetable_data[6])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_8_1, timetable_data[7])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_9_1, timetable_data[8])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_10_1, timetable_data[9])

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_1_2, timetable_data[10])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_2_2, timetable_data[11])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_3_2, timetable_data[12])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_4_2, timetable_data[13])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_5_2, timetable_data[14])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_6_2, timetable_data[15])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_7_2, timetable_data[16])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_8_2, timetable_data[17])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_9_2, timetable_data[18])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_10_2, timetable_data[19])

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_1_3, timetable_data[20])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_2_3, timetable_data[21])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_3_3, timetable_data[22])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_4_3, timetable_data[23])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_5_3, timetable_data[24])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_6_3, timetable_data[25])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_7_3, timetable_data[26])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_8_3, timetable_data[27])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_9_3, timetable_data[28])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_10_3, timetable_data[29])

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_1_4, timetable_data[30])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_2_4, timetable_data[31])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_3_4, timetable_data[32])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_4_4, timetable_data[33])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_5_4, timetable_data[34])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_6_4, timetable_data[35])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_7_4, timetable_data[36])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_8_4, timetable_data[37])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_9_4, timetable_data[38])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_10_4, timetable_data[39])

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_1_5, timetable_data[40])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_2_5, timetable_data[41])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_3_5, timetable_data[42])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_4_5, timetable_data[43])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_5_5, timetable_data[44])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_6_5, timetable_data[45])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_7_5, timetable_data[46])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_8_5, timetable_data[47])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_9_5, timetable_data[48])
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.table_10_5, timetable_data[49])

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent)
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)
}

fun readCSV(context: Context): ArrayList<String>{
    var lines: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    val file = File( context.getString(R.string.timetable_path) )
    val fileInputStream: FileInputStream
    val input: Scanner
    try {
        fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        input = Scanner(fileInputStream, "UTF-8")
        lines = input.nextLine().split(",").toTypedArray().toCollection(ArrayList())
        Log.d("CORRECT", lines.joinToString())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Log.e("TAG", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
    }
    return lines
}
```

==============

Update (18/5):

<s>I accidentally solved the problem by adding the following to the manifest but I am not sure why it's working. I thought these permission is given by default?</s>

Please tell me if someone figures it out.

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To give some extra information, I find two errors in the logcat that maybe related. I tried the above approach because of the second error I listed out below.

```
W/AppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
```

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: failed to add asset path data/app/____________/base.apk
```

==============

Update (18/5 Late night):

After a day, the problem is still here. After further testing, it looks like errors related to the emulator. Since if I start a new emulator and install the app, it should be all find.

I cannot find a way to reproduce the bug every time I tried to do that but it seems only appear after uninstall and reinstall the app.

Everytime the following error code will be found if the bug occurs.

```
2020-05-18 22:08:22.670 2102-2102/? W/WidgetPreviewLoader: Can't load widget preview drawable 0x7f07007c for provider: ComponentInfo{[packetName]/[packetName].TimetableWidget}
2020-05-18 22:08:22.790 2102-2102/? E/AppWidgetHostView: Package name [packetName] not found
2020-05-18 22:08:22.796 2102-2102/? W/AppWidgetHostView: Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(UserHandle{0}/ComponentInfo{[packetName]/[packetName].TimetableWidget}): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Page %1$d of %2$d from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c0045
2020-05-18 22:08:22.830 2102-2102/? E/AppWidgetHostView: Package name [packetName] not found
2020-05-18 22:08:22.856 2102-2102/? W/AppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Page %1$d of %2$d from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c0045
```

Comment: I got exactly the same issue, but no solution yet to that... :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet sure it only happens on emulators, but I noticed that if the **previously installed** version of the app has `android:allowBackup="true"` then this bug happens. If you set `android:allowBackup="false"` and then uninstall + reinstall the app, this issue does not happen.